# Show column headers again in split ListView

Tags: wpf, listview, gridview

I have a `ListView` with a `ItemsPanel` like this:

```
        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <UniformGrid Columns="2" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
```

And for `ListView.View` I have a `GridView` with multiple columns. The problem is I can see the column headers in the first column only (of `UniformGrid`). I need to show the column headers of `GridView` in the second column also. How to do this?

Example code:

```
    <ListView>
        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <UniformGrid Columns="2" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridView.Columns>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Day" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Day}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Month" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Month}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Year" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Year}" />
                </GridView.Columns>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
        <ListView.Items>
            <sys:DateTime />
            <sys:DateTime />
            <sys:DateTime />
        </ListView.Items>
    </ListView>
```

[image]

Comment: could you share some screen? may we have a look. could you  share the full xaml too. also appreciated if you can share your expected result maybe a simple sketch or drawing.

Comment: do you look forward to see like this http://imgur.com/i9I5G3P

Comment: @PushprajRuhal : Yep, Exactly like that

Answer (score 1):

I tried to get your expected appearance. So what I did

- created an ItemsControl as main container
- set UniformGrid as the items panel for ItemsControl
- created a data template for ItemsControl using ListView with headers
- binded ItemsSource of ListView to the Item from ItemsControl
- most important the data then becomes a collection of collection

please feel free to adjust the sample according to your usage

```
    <ItemsControl>
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <UniformGrid Columns="2" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                    <ListView.View>
                        <GridView>
                            <GridView.Columns>
                                <GridViewColumn Header="Day" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Day}" />
                                <GridViewColumn Header="Month" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Month}" />
                                <GridViewColumn Header="Year" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Year}" />
                            </GridView.Columns>
                        </GridView>
                    </ListView.View>
                </ListView>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <ItemsControl.Items>
            <x:Array Type="{x:Type sys:DateTime}">
                <sys:DateTime />
            </x:Array>
            <x:Array Type="{x:Type sys:DateTime}">
                <sys:DateTime />
            </x:Array>
            <x:Array Type="{x:Type sys:DateTime}">
                <sys:DateTime />
            </x:Array>
        </ItemsControl.Items>
    </ItemsControl>
```

**2nd Method**

```
    <ItemsControl>
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <UniformGrid Columns="2" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <TextBlock Text="Day" Background="LightGray"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Month" Grid.Column="1" Background="LightGray"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Year" Grid.Column="2" Background="LightGray"/>

                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Day}" Grid.Row="1"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Month}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Year}" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <ItemsControl.Items>
            <sys:DateTime />
            <sys:DateTime />
            <sys:DateTime />
        </ItemsControl.Items>
    </ItemsControl>
```

Comment: I don't want to go down this path as this would mean that I have to split up my collection. I would rather not have the headers than doing this. I'm looking for a solution that does not involve a change in the viewmodel. Thanks for your input anyway.

Comment: I added another method to achieve the same without changing the model, see if this can be used. header text blocks can be styled as needed.